# TexWorks open but no preview window

Tags: texworks

I am completely new to TexWorks, and just downloaded it on windows 10.

Everything is fine except that when I open it, only the editor window shows, and there is no pdf preview window. For some reason, I can’t find any option to show the window. So basically my texworks is just the text editor and nothing else.

Is there any way I can manually set to show the preview window? or do I just reinstall everything again?

Thanks so much in advance for your responses.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There should be "Window -> Goto Preview". Have you installed a TeX system (TeXworks is just an editor which should ship with TeX Live and MikTeX, so installing it separately seems unnecessary)?

Comment: @TeXnician there is no GoTo preview option when i press window ):

Comment: Although it should be there. What about the TeX system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking there are not really  any "pre-view" but a "post-view". Probably this leads to think that there are something wrong in your installation, but probably is working fine.

When you start `texworks` empty or with a new  file, said `somefile.tex` file, there are no any "preview" window simply because still there are nothing rendered to show.

But once you compile successfully  that new file (green upper-left buttom) with the right compiler (after selecting `pdfLaTeX` or whatevercompatible with that file) and the `somefile.pdf` is created, then the "preview" must appear to the right of the editor window.

If you close `texworks` and run again `texworks somefile.tex` now the preview window is opened immediately at the start since the PDF `somefile.pdf` already exist in the same directory.

If you close the preview window but not the editor you can open again the preview with a new compilation or (without compiling again) in the menu `Window > Preview`. If the preview is open but hidden by the editor window or another program, this or `Window > somefile.pdf` also will put the focus in the preview window. Of course, this cannot work if you move/delete the PDF file meanwhile.

Comment: Thanks so much!! this helped. is it possible to generate a live view? or do i have to keep pressing the green play button? thanks again

Comment: Not in texworks, unless you run also some script to run the compiler in the background every x seconds. Gummi for example can do that, and it is nice for testing a "Hello word" or so, but  believe me, you will not want live previews in large projects, and is not at all a best practice, as you will be constantly aware of the changes in the output instead of be focused on the right LaTeX syntax, and more important, on writing the text.